# Weblogic Unresolved Webapp Library references for WebAppModule in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic

I'm trying to deploy my web application in weblogic server 12c but i am deployment exception like below can some one help me please(I have upgraded jersy version 2.5.1)

### exception

```
<Dec 9, 2019 7:35:17,517 AM GMT> <Error> <Deployer> <WL-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "CDMWebWar" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "WebAppModule(CDMWebWar:CDMWeb.war)", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jax-rs, Specification-Version: 2, exact-match: false]
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "WebAppModule(CDMWebWar:CDMWeb.war)", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jax-rs, Specification-Version: 2, exact-match: false]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.mergeWebAppLibraries(WebAppModule.java:546)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processWebAppLibraries(WebAppModule.java:470)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:707)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Dec 9, 2019 7:35:20,126 AM GMT> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <WL-2192511> <The list of resource packages: com.verizon.webkit.tsmarker.appmonitor;com.verizon.webkit.tsmarker.apps> 
CSMWLJobListener:contextInitialized Event
<Dec 9, 2019 7:35:23,651 AM GMT> <Error> <Deployer> <WL-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "CDMWebWar".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Module null can not be activated, not in ACTIVATED state: NEW
    at weblogic.diagnostics.module.WLDFModule.activate(WLDFModule.java:328)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:207)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:57)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy the JAX-RS library then you can try deploying your application. You can refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF297)